Is it possible to upload a pdf file on arXiv
I have written a paper with Latex (overleaf) and submitted it to a journal. I would also like to publish a preprint in arXiv. Unfortunately, arXiv does not seem to allow pdf uploads but just wants the tex files. The big problem when uploading my latex files is that the created pdf file from arXiv looks extremely bad. So apparently it is using another compiler than in overleaf. So my question is if there is a way to upload the pdf directly on arXiv or you have any clue how I can change the latex compiling in arXiv (I have to admit that I have no experience with something like this).

This question is similar to: Is there any advantage of putting source tex file on arXiv?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Anyon The OP says: "The big problem when uploading my latex files is that the created pdf file from arXiv looks extremely bad." That issue isn't mentioned in the question that you linked to (nor in its answers).  Apparently, arXiv produces PDF from LaTeX in a different way than Overleaf.

@AndreasBlass Right, but OP wants to get around it by uploading a PDF which isn't possible if the PDF is generated from a tex source.

You can force pdflatex as outlined here: https://info.arxiv.org/help/submit_tex.html If that doesn't help it may be better to ask for help on the TeX StackExchange.

@Anyon I agree that OP's proposed solutions don't look promising, but there might, for example, be a way to tell Overleaf to process LaTeX the same way that arXiv does. Although I've never used Overleaf myself, two of my coauthors have, without any LaTeX-to-PDF problems, and I imagine that it would be useful to have more information about what's affected by the compilation difference and how one could work around those thiings.

@AndreasBlass I'm pretty sure Overleaf defaults to pdfLaTeX, but also has support for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Which one OP is using is unclear, as is which packages are used and whether both platforms have the same versions...

Depending on your field, other *XiVs take PDFs.

No, you cannot upload a PDF generated from latex to arXiv.
Overleaf does not directly compile latex; it uses pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, or latex under the hood.  You can check how Overleaf is compiling your paper in the options.  You may need to modify your paper in some way to make it look good on aXiv.
There might also be errors in the compilation of your paper on Overleaf.  In this case you will see a red number near the top of the screen and if you click on it it will show the errors.  Overleaf will try to show you the paper in spite of the errors, but arXiv will fail if there are any errors.
I recommend figuring out more specifically what is causing your paper to "look bad" and then posting a question on tex.SE if necessary.

Actually, you can upload a PDF generated from latex. You just need to "launder" it first, e.g., run it through OCR software, that first scans every page as an image then OCRs. It won't look as good, but it's technically possible. Now, whether you should do this, vs the time it takes to fight latex and make the original compile in the arxiv compiler, is a different question.

Overleaf is not a latex compiler.? typo?

I don't think it's a typo. I would refer to overleaf as a LaTeX (online) editor. The compiling is still done by pdflatex, lualatex, or xelatex. Any way, I agree with David's answer that the best way to actually fix the LaTeX code (which in all likeliness contains errors that overleaf just chooses to ignore) and then upload it to arXiv.

The 'compiler' is the same. What may be different are the versions of the style (extension .sty) and class files (extension .cls), in particular if these are not standard, that are provided on arXiv and overleaf.
To avoid this, just ship those files together with your source.
However, w/o more specific information about in which way your paper looks bad, we cannot help you here. Actually stackexchange TeX may be a better place to ask.
